# Android grid view issues

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, simplecursoradapter

I'm a beginner in android development. In the application that i'm working on , data is being displayed from a database to a list view using the default simple cursor adapter(not subclassing it).

I want to add the option to display the data in a grid view as well , if the user desires.

I checked out some examples in the web and it seemed identical to the list view. So again im fetching the data from the database using a simple cursor adapter and displaying it on the grid view.

All of the items are being displaying correctly at first , that is until i begin scrolling it. Everything gets mixed up then.

Each grid view item has 2 textviews, the first one displaying its title and the second one it's description. So, when scrolling, descriptions get mixed up , item titles with the wrong descriptions etc. Also sometimes the entire grid view dissapears completely.

I never had such issues with my listview , it always worked as intended.

What am i missing here? Would appreciate your insight.

UPDATE :

The grid view dissappearing when scrolling was due to grid view items being uneven in height.

It seems that my other issue lies within the viewbinder that i've set for the adapter. If i comment out the following code , i no longer get mixups between grid view items.
Here's the viewbinder code :

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

public boolean setViewValue(View aView, Cursor aCursor, int aColumnIndex) {


    if (aColumnIndex == 3) {

           String color = aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex);
       aView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

           return true;
         }

        if (aColumnIndex == 4) {

       if (aCursor.getString(5)!=null) {

          ViewGroup parentview = (ViewGroup)aView.getParent();
                       parentview.removeAllViews();

          TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout (MainActivity.this);
                       parentview.addView(tablelayout);

          int count = Integer.parseInt(aCursor.getString(5));

          String[] texts = convertStringToArray(aCursor.getString(4));
          String[] cb = convertStringToArray(aCursor.getString(6));

          for (int i =0;i<count;i++) {

           LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
           View checklist_row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_row_layout, null);
           TextView tv = (TextView)checklist_row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           ImageView im = (ImageView)checklist_row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

           if (cb[i].equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cbc);

        tv.setText(texts[i]);
        parentview.addView(checklist_row);

        }
         return true;
    }

    else {

       TextView tv = (TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       tv.setText(aCursor.getString(4));

           return true;

         }

    }

    return false;

 }
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i suggested it's problem in your **getView()** method.in Listview and gridview use the adapter class for display the data.in android many adapter.so i advice to first read about **how to use the adapter?**
Here i give one link witch helpful understand  use of adapter.[BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and also use his link where i display the whole code to how to use  the **getView()** method.[Use of getView method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522874/optimize-listview-performance-android/13523158#13523158) i hope you got the solution of your problem.

**EDIT:**

i suggest to use this link here simple example of use the cursor adapter.[Simple example of cursor adapter](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) and also this link similar as your problem.[Cursor Adapter with Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582965/how-to-use-cursoradapter)

i hope you will get your answer.
Thanks.

Comment: From what i've read, simple cursor adapter does not have a getview() method. Correct? So i will need to override the newview() and bindview() methods of the simple cursor adapter?

Comment: @PanagiotisMoraitis here i update my answer so see and implement.